# SwiftUI: Changing list cell appearance when selected

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

In SwiftUI, I have a `List` where the cells contain images which I want to change depending on whether the cell is selected. (The images are tinted SF Symbols, and I want to draw them untinted when selected because it looks better, which I do by setting the `isTemplate` property.)

Below is a simplified version of my code. It works, with one small problem - there is a slight delay before the image actually changes after the cell is selected/deselected. The delay is a fraction of a second after the mouse is released, so with drag-selecting it becomes very noticeable. How can I achieve this so that the change is instant?

I'm guessing it's because the `selection` binding doesn't get updated until after the mouse event handling is finished. So how can I react to the changes happening *during* the event? I would have expected an `@Environment` key for selected state, but I don't see one.

```
  var body: some View
  {
    List(changes, id: \.path, selection: $selection) {
      ItemCell(fileChange: $0, selected: selection.contains($0.path))
    }
  }
```

```
struct ItemCell: View
{
  let item: MyItem
  let selected: Bool

  var body: some View
  {
    HStack {
      // (other things in the cell)
      // The `image` property is computed and loads a new NSImage every time
      Image(nsImage: item.image.asTemplate(selected))
    }
  }
}
```

```
extension NSImage
{
  func asTemplate(_ template: Bool) -> NSImage
  {
    isTemplate = template
    return self
  }
}
```

**Update:**
I tried using a `Label` to display the icon instead because that displays symbol images using the accent color, and changes the color (instantly) to white when the row is selected. But I also need to vary the icon color (eg, the "deleted" icon is red), and `.tint()`, `.listItemTint()` and `.accentColor()` all fail to change the color, while `.foregroundColor()` loses the automatic change to white when selected.

```
    Label("", systemImage: item.symbolName)
      .tint(item.symbolColor) // has no effect
      // makes the icon always white
      //.labelStyle(.iconOnly)
```

Stats: macOS 12.5.1, Xcode 13.4.1

Comment: Maybe it is image loading effect, actually needed MRE to investigate.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by image loading effect. The NSTableView implementation that I'm replacing loads the image the same way, and has no delay.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: applying `listItemTint()` to the enclosing `HStack`, rather than to the `Label` directly, gets the desired color *and* the white-when-selected behavior.

Also, using `.labelStyle(.iconOnly)` still cancels that out and makes the icon white, and an empty string makes the layout a little wrong, but using `EmptyView` for the title works better:

```
    Label(title: { EmptyView() },
          icon: { Image(systemName: symbol )})
```